# Rspec issues with helper on decorator on view test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, view-helpers, draper

One of my rspec tests fails because I can't use a helper method on a decorator rendering a view, while the view works perfectly while running the server normally, here's the error

```
1) dashboard/index.html.haml render all translations
   Failure/Error: render
   ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `dashboard?' for #<#<Class:0x0000000a9d1020>:0x0000000c2286f0>
```

the following method is a simple boolean check called inside a decorator method called from the rendered view:

```
items << h.link_to(...) if h.dashboard?
```

And the helper method:

```
def dashboard?
  controller_name == "dashboard"
end
```

I can import the helper module into the decorator but then the error changes to controller_name is undefined, so I guess my question is in two parts:

One, how can I get the helper method to work when the decorator is called from a rendered view through Rspec, and two, how can I set the controller_name to work within the Rspec test.

Comment: Any solution about this? I have the same issue but using Devise's current_user helper in the decorator :/

Answer (score 0):

Your test is looking for a method called `dashboard?` which doesn't appear defined within your code.

You can either update your test to look for the method `moderators_dashboard?`

Or

Change `def moderators_dashboard?` to `def dashboard?`

Comment: I guess I erased something around when pasting the code, but there's no dashboard?, it is moderators_dashboard? Everywhere, I'll edit it for clarity